# Powershell IO.FileSystemWatcher - folder not updated for last 30 mins

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, system.io.file

I am looking for help in my Powershell script.

If Directory log location C:\Users\10146187\Downloads\Syslogd does not have any new file created or changed for last 30 minutes, I want to run function "RunMyStuff". Also i do not have Unregister-function. Not sure, where do i put it. Thanks.

```
Function RunMyStuff {
        # this is the bit I want to happen when there is no file created for 30 mins under C:\Users\10146187\Downloads\Syslogd
     Start-Process 'C:\windows\system32\calc.exe'
     Write-Host $global:FileCreated
    }
    
    Function Watch {    
        $global:FileCreated = $false 
        $folder = "C:\Users\10146187\Downloads\Syslogd"
        $filter = "*.*"
        $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
            IncludeSubdirectories = $false 
            EnableRaisingEvents = $true
        }
    
        Register-ObjectEvent $Watcher "Created" -Action {$global:FileCreated = $true} > $null
         
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 120
        
        while($true){
            while ($global:FileCreated -eq $true){
                 Start-Sleep -Seconds 600
                 Write-Host $global:FileCreated
            }
           
            RunMyStuff
            
            $global:FileCreated = $false
        }
    }
    
    Watch
```

Comment: that stuff is to act _when an action occurs_. why are you trying to use it for _when and action DOES NOT occur in a given time frame? ///// the more sensible technique seems to be to use task scheduler to run every 10 or 15 minutes to check for "has anything changed in the last xx minutes?".

Comment: What if you were to create two event handlers - one as you are now for the FileSystemWatcher and a second one on a System.Timers.Timer object (System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler).

Start the timer, the start the watcher.  If the timer elapses before the watcher event, then you'll know nothing has changed.  If the watcher fires before the timer elapses, then reset the timer event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an example of what you're looking for.  It uses a Timer event with a FileWatcher event.

```ps
function RunMyStuff()
{
    Write-Host "$(get-date) RunMyStuff (no files added within last 10 seconds)"
    # Start-Process "calc.exe"
}

function Watch ($folder) {
    Write-Host "Watching $((Get-Item $folder).Fullname)"
    $global:FileCreated = $true

    $filter = "*.*"
    $watcher = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{ 
        IncludeSubdirectories = $false
        EnableRaisingEvents = $true
    }
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $watcher -EventName "Created" -SourceIdentifier "myFileWatcher" -Action { 
        $global:timer.Stop()
        $global:FileCreated = $true
        $global:timer.Start()
    } > $null

    $global:timer = New-Object Timers.Timer
    $global:timer.Interval = 10000
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $global:timer -EventName "Elapsed" -SourceIdentifier "myTimer" -Action {
        $global:FileCreated = $false
    } > $null

    $global:timer.Start()

    try {
        while ($true) {
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
            if (!$global:FileCreated) {
                RunMyStuff
                $global:FileCreated = $true
            }
        }
    }
    finally {
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "myFileWatcher"
        Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier "myTimer"
    }
}

Watch "C:\"
```

Here it is in action: [image]

Comment: thanks but it just fires for me every second. did you make any modifications in code above ?

Comment: @Powershel only difference was the message in `RunMyStuff`.  I updated the script to be the same.  Works the same with PowerShell Core 7.1 and PowerShell 5.1

Comment: Thanks. do you know how to make it persist during server restarts ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, Task Scheduler could be used to start the script by creating a task that is started at system startup.